# How to know the time that packet takes to travel from client to server?

Tags: network-programming

I am working on a project and I want to know the time between client and server that packet takes to reach it destination. I am using a raspberry pi as client and my laptop as server.  The connection between the server and client will be socket connection. So, I want to send an image from client to the server and take the timestamps in both ending to know the time.

Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't send an image to measure a single packet time. The image might require multiple packets to be sent and you'll end up measuring more than you wanted.

Second, using timestamp on both ends is not very reliable as it depends on the time synchronization between the systems which is hard to achieve and maintain.

Third, don't reinvent the wheel. If you want to measure communication lag, use PING. Its tried and tested, its efficient and its implemented for you so it's faster & cheaper to use and you don't risk adding bugs of your own.

Comment: would you please be more specific. Where can I used PING ? How can I implement it on raspberry pi ? etc.

Comment: Do you know what ping is? If you don't, Google it

Comment: I do not think you read my question carefully. How come I ping over the raspberry pi ?